# How to filter a HTML table based on selected value less that a table cell's value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I want to filter a table's display from a database based on the selected value.

I want to display table rows when the 7th cell index of each row is less than Selected value, by comparing the integer/string value.

I found lots of examples of matching or containing criteria, but I couldn't figure out Less Than or Greater than, currently my code displays table but not working properly.

I am happy to accept jQuery if it works too.

```
<table id="carTable" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Make</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Seats</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Price/Day
        <select id='filterText' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterPrice()'>
            <option value="all" selected>All</option>
            <option value='69'> < 69 </option>
            <option value='100'> < 100 </option>
            <option value='200'> < 200 </option>
            <option value='500'> < 500 </option>
        </select>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="carsTable">
    {%for car in cars%}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ car[0] }}</td>
      <td>{{ car[1] }}</td>
      <td>{{ car[2] }}</td>
      <td>{{ car[3] }}</td>
      <td>{{ car[4] }}</td>
      <td>{{ car[5] }}</td>
      <td>{{ car[6] }}</td>
      <td>{{ car[7] }}</td>
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My function looks like this

```
function filterPrice() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("filterText");
    filter = input.value;
    table = document.getElementById("carTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[7];
      if (td) {
        cellValue = td.innerHTML;
        if (cellValue <= filter) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwLmJ.jpg)

Comment: Your main trouble is that you're comparing strings. Convert them to integers or floats before comparison.

Comment: omg, thank you so much, I was stuck on this for 3 hours....

Comment: I added parseInt() and it works like a charm, thanks man.

Comment: I would also assume that your search for `tr` should do so against the `tbody`, and not the entire table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by convert to integers first then compare, thanks to @isherwood

```
function filterPrice() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, cellValue;
    input = document.getElementById("filterText");
    filter = parseInt(input.value);
    table = document.getElementById("carTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[7];
      if (td) {
        cellValue = parseInt(td.innerHTML);
        if (cellValue <= filter) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Good deal. Be sure to accept this answer to resolve the question.